# Scroll nested within resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some jquery and my objective is this:

If screen size is greater than 981, then I want to track the scroll event and do some css changes.

If screen size is less than 981, then I don't want to track the scroll event and instead simply apply some css styles.

And I want to check this condition during resizing also.

My jquery code is below, but the problem is that when I resize the window and while resizing, make it below 981 width, then the scroll event continues to get tracked and things within it get executed.

```
        $(window).on("resize", function () {
var screenwidth = $(window).width();
if ( screenwidth > 981) {
    $(window).scroll(function()
{   
    var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();

    if ( wintop>100)
    {
        //always in view
                    console.log('test100');
        $('#slider-top-box').css({ "position":"relative","margin-top":"70px" });
                    $('#news-top-box').css({ "z-index":"1","margin-top":"-70px","background-color":"transparent","padding":"inherit" });
    }
    else
    {
                    $('#slider-top-box').css({ "position":"fixed","margin-top":"0px" });
                    $('#news-top-box').css({ "z-index":"1","margin-top":"0px","background-color":"transparent","padding-top":"380px" });
    }
});
} else {
    $('#slider-top-box').css({ "position":"relative","margin-top":"0px" });
    $('#news-top-box').css({ "padding-top":"50px" });
}}).resize();
```

Comment: I created a jsbin to show this. instead of 981 I have showcased with a smaller cutoff point 481. To test the issue, 1)make output size greater tahn 481, then scroll. here scroll event should track. Now make output box width less than 480. Now scroll should not be tracked but it is. https://jsbin.com/pabahad/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the event handler when you don't want it tracked.

Use `$(window).off("scroll");` in your `else` statement:

```
        $(window).on("resize", function () {
var screenwidth = $(window).width();
if ( screenwidth > 981) {
    $(window).scroll(function()
{   
    var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();

    if ( wintop>100)
    {
        //always in view
                    console.log('test100');
        $('#slider-top-box').css({ "position":"relative","margin-top":"70px" });
                    $('#news-top-box').css({ "z-index":"1","margin-top":"-70px","background-color":"transparent","padding":"inherit" });
    }
    else
    {
                    $('#slider-top-box').css({ "position":"fixed","margin-top":"0px" });
                    $('#news-top-box').css({ "z-index":"1","margin-top":"0px","background-color":"transparent","padding-top":"380px" });
    }
});
} else {
    $(window).off("scroll");
    $('#slider-top-box').css({ "position":"relative","margin-top":"0px" });
    $('#news-top-box').css({ "padding-top":"50px" });
}}).resize();
```